# Getting xml data and writing to db from external source

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, xml-parsing

I have spent the past three days researching this... but Im still stuck.

I have a service provider that offers me a REST api. I need to:
Get the data from his api
Assign the data to variables in php
Write the data to my localhost sql database.

All that's required is the API KEY which has been provided to me.

Please could someone explain to me what method I should use to call and store the data in php.
Writing to the Database and handling the data once in php format is not a problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to consume a webservice you would have to make HTTP request using PHP.

There is many ways to do that but the most used(IMHO) is [cURL](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php). cURL function would allow you to easily make HTTP request and consume data from the webservice.

Comment: Well that definitely solves my main question. I just purchased SPIDERS, AND SCREEN SCRAPERS
A Guide to Developing Internet Agents with PHP/CURL.
I hope this will be able to guide me successfully in the ways of cURL

Comment: Well I went through the book, and I have just done my first API Integration where I pull the Data, write to my own db and then put the data back out in my own reporting system.

Thanks Ragez for setting me straight :)